# fatal error: module 'flutter_web_auth' not found

Tags: flutter

When running the project on a simulator everything seems to work fine. Once i tried to deploy to an actual device I get the following error:

iOS Version - 13.0

Xcode Version - 11.3.1

Flutter Version - 1.12.13+hotfix.8

```
Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...
Building App.framework for arm64...

Building App.framework for armv7...
Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...             30.5s
Built to build/aot/.
warning: parsing line table prologue at offset 0x6f697463 found unsupported
version 0x00
warning: line table parameters mismatch. Cannot emit.
note: while processing
/Users/<Username>/Documents/flutter_test_app/build/aot/armv7/snapsho
t_assembly.o
Project /Users/<Username>/Documents/flutter_test_app built and
packaged successfully.
/Users/<Username>/Documents/flutter_test_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPlu
ginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'flutter_web_auth' not found
@import flutter_web_auth;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/Users/<Username>/Documents/flutter_test_app/ios/Runner/GeneratedPlu
ginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'flutter_web_auth' not found
@import flutter_web_auth;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error running application on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added flutter we bauth dependency plugin in your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter_web_auth: ^0.1.3
```

If it's added and it still does not works, ensure also that the pod install works fine to add the plugin.

Comment: how would I make sure that pod install works fine? Sorry this is my first time using flutter.

Comment: It depends on your environment development. Do you use command line or IDE to compile and run?